# Unable to update deploy server url during postflight event

Tags: installation, plugin-events

When I install myplugin the very first time, it should update the `location` column in `#__update_sites` table with updated string which includes the API key.

I'm unable to update at first install as I my query doesnt get the `update_site_id` from `#__update_sites_extensions`.

I wonder why? Due to this I'm unable to update the string. Only following installation can.

Can anyone advise, at which stage joomla actually updates the `#__update_sites_extensions` with the `location/ url`?

Also is there a way to prevent Joomla inserting into this table the `url` on every installation?

in xml file:

```
<updateservers>
<server type="extension" name="myplugin Update Site">https://test.com/jupdates/manifest/myplugin</server>
</updateservers>
```

In script.php

```
public function postflight()
    {
       $extensionId = $this->getExtensionId();
       $updateSiteId = $this->updateSiteId($extensionId);
       $defaultLocation = 'https://test.com/jupdates/manifest/myplugin';
       $location = $defaultLocation . '?apikey=' . APIKEY;
```

> update the location string with api key

```
       $db = JFactory::getDBO();
       $query = array();
       $query   = 'UPDATE '. $db->quoteName('#__update_sites')
            . ' SET ' . $db->quoteName('location') . ' = ' . $db->Quote($location)
            . ' WHERE ' . $db->quoteName('update_site_id') . ' = ' . $db->Quote($updateSiteId);

       $db->setQuery($query);
       $db->query();
    }
```

functions:

```
public function getExtensionId()
{
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();

    $query = array();
    $query[] = 'SELECT ' . $db->quoteName('extension_id') . ' FROM ' . $db->quoteName('#__extensions');
    $query[] = 'WHERE ' . $db->quoteName('element') . '=' . $db->Quote('myplugin');
    $query[] = 'AND ' . $db->quoteName('type') . '=' . $db->Quote('plugin');

    $query = implode(' ', $query);

    $db->setQuery($query);

    $extensionId = $db->loadResult();


    return $extensionId;
}

public function updateSiteId($extensionId)
{
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();

    $query = array();
    $query[] = 'SELECT ' . $db->quoteName('update_site_id') . ' FROM ' . $db->quoteName('#__update_sites_extensions');
    $query[] = 'WHERE ' . $db->quoteName('extension_id') . '=' . $db->Quote($extensionId);

    $query = implode(' ', $query);
    $db->setQuery($query);

    $updateSiteId = $db->loadResult();


    return $updateSiteId;
}
```

Comment: Inside your `postflight` function, what happens if you add `var_dump($extensionId); var_dump($updateSiteId); exit;`? You should get some data dumped either on the page or in your browser console.

Answer (score 1):

The update server definition is not loaded to the database until the `onExtensionAfterInstall` event is dispatched, and this depends on the "Extension - Joomla" plugin being enabled.